# CORS Policy blocking api request in Vite

Tags: reactjs, cors, vite

I'm having a CORS problem when i try to make a request to an API. I added default headers as a possible solution I saw on some forums, but that still didn't solve the problem. I still get this error above:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/locale/city?name=itabira&token=02f4d93d43de2aced8cf31cd80a791e9'
> from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Default headers

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] =
  "application/json;charset=utf-8";

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1",
});
```

API call

```
 const handleSearch = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await api.get(
        `/locale/city?name=${city}&token=02f4d93d43de2aced8cf31cd80a791e9`
      );
      const data = await response.data;
      setResults(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: … The server controls CORS, not the client; that wouldn’t make sense.

Comment: Yes, i know. but how do i solve this?

Comment: Find out how the server controls access? Use a proxy? Idk, I don’t know anything about that API. You probably should if you’re using it, though.

Comment: you´re right, but i dit not found anything about this on the docs. i´ll probably try to use some other wheather api.

Comment: _"Yes, i know."_ - if you did, then why did you try something as pointless as setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a _request_ header.

Answer (score -1):

Sending requests from one host to another isn't considered a good practice.

In your case, the API server doesn't permit indicating the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

You can use a proxy, which is documented here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: FWIW using a proxy would be sending a request from one host to another. It’s not about “good practice” or not, it’s about how an API works and what it does/doesn’t allow.